# net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.ItemNotFoundException

Tags: .net, vb.net, openstack

using vb.net 2017 (15.7.5 (current)) and openstack.net (tried both 1.7.6 and 1.7.7 (current)), I am getting the following exception:

net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.ItemNotFoundException

I tried putting the offending code in a try catch block using both

catch ex as exception

and

catch ex as net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.ItemNotFoundException

and for each in debug mode the catch works fine and the code works as expected.

However, in each in release mode I get the following:

> net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.ItemNotFoundException
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message=The item was not found or does not exist.
>   Source=openstacknet   StackTrace:    blah, blah, blah ..

any ideas for a workaround / fix (other than on error goto because there is already a higher level try block in play).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get this while debugging it in Visual Studio or by running the EXE itself?

Comment: I originally got in when running the exe, but recreated it when running in release mode in visual studio - but not in debug mode with exact same code.

Comment: Try resetting the [exception settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger) in VS and make sure that that specific exception isn't checked to break when thrown.

Comment: That worked around it in release mode in Visual Studio.  However, the .exe still fails.

Comment: Odd... Are you sure it's the same code throwing the exception in the EXE (if you follow the Stack Trace)? I also think a lot depends on what your code looks like and where it is run. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project as well (`Build > Clean YourProjectName` and `Build > Rebuild YourProjectName`).

Comment: Thanks - that didn't make a difference - but helped me to figure out where the problem may be a little more - although still not resolved the lightbulb came on that the released .exe version is obsfucated and the debug version is not - so that is likely where the problem lies.  Will dig deeper.